# How to split contents of a single column into 2 columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm using Excel 2003. I have a spreadsheet that currently has 500 rows of data and just one column (A). For example, the first five rows look like this:

```
          A
  1  loremipsum=fufu.com
  2  heyheyhey=wuwu.com
  3  youyouyouyou=dudu.com 
  4  helloworld=huhu.com
  5  happyhappy=mumu.com
```

I want to reformat all 500 rows so that the portion of the data after the `=` sign on each row is moved to a new column (B), and the `=` sign is deleted. Thus, the data will occupy in two columns (A & B), and the first five rows (1-5) will look like this:

```
         A            B 
 1  loremipsum     fufu.com
 2  heyheyhey      wuwu.com 
 3  youyouyouyou   dudu.com 
 4  helloworld     huhu.com  
 5  happyhappy     mumu.com
```

Can you tell me how to set up a macro? (assuming the solution entails a trip on the macro magic carpet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formulas

column B: `=MID(A1,1,FIND("=",A1)-1)` → autofill down
column C: `=MID(A1,FIND("=",A1)+1,LEN(A1))` → autofill down
delete column A afterwards

Comment: Thank you for cleaning up (editing) the formatting of my question. Also, thank you for your answer. As it turns out, I unintentionally neglected to include the fact that the data in some of the rows contained more than one "=" sign, e.g.: loremipsum=fufu.com/foo=foo?moo=moo  . However, your solution still works just the way you suggested. It creates a break after the first "=" sign, and dumps the rest of the line (including any additional "=" signs) into the next column. Perfect! Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Select the column, click Data > Text to columns > Delimited > check "Other" and enter a = sign > finish

Comment: thank you for your answer. As presented, the sample data set and the outcome I defined for it would be handled well by your solution. Regrettably, I neglected to include the fact that the data in some of the rows contains more than one "=" sign, e.g.: loremipsum=fufu.com/foo=foo?moo=moo  . So your solution solved the issue as I presented it, but not as I should have presented it. Perhaps you or someone in the community can instruct me how best to acknowledge your contribution under these circumstances? Regardless....thank you!

Comment: To acknowledge an answer as useful you can upvote it by clicking the arrow above the number. Once you have 15 rep points, you can upvote answers.